# Eloquent relationship mass assignment $guarded ignored

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three table in DB, and I have used belongsTo for merging them. My Admins model looks like this :

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['status', 'shop_name', 'vendor_id', 'id'];

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    public function getVendorDetails(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class, 'vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }

    public function getVendorBusinessDetails(){
        return $this->belongsTo(VendorBusinessDetails::class, 'vendor_id','vendor_id');
    }

}
```

I need to prevent `shop-name` field to be saved through form. this field is in the table name : `vendor_business_detals` (getVendorBusinessDetails).But in this case $guarded only works for Admins table and ignores another relationship tables and fields of them such as `shop_name`. In short I am struggling to find the way to add `$guarded` data for `VendorBusinessDetails`. My controller looks like below:

```
 $business_data = $request->only(['shop_name', 'shop_address', 'shop_phone']);
//dd($business_data);
                    $myModel = Admin::find($id);
                    //business table update
                    $myModel->getVendorBusinessDetails()->update($business_data);
```

VendorBusinessDetails model:

```
class VendorBusinessDetails extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['shop_name'];
    protected $table = 'vendors_business_details';
}
```

I don't know why `$guraded=['shop_name']` is ignored. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are calling `update` directly on a Builder, that is a direct `UPDATE` query that does not set any attributes on the model so mass assignment isn't in play here hence no 'guarded'/'fillable' being checked ... you would have to call `update` on a model instance not the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$myModel->getVendorBusinessDetails()->update($business_data);
```

If you use "getVendorBusinessDetails" as a method, the model isn't initialize. Only the SQL update command runs.

```php
$myModel->getVendorBusinessDetails->update($business_data);
```

Using "getVendorBusinessDetails" as a field initializes the model. So, it works as you expected.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But when we need the update like I showed you? isn't it mass assignment? Because in that case it is assigned also. Do we need to use `$myModel->getVendorBusinessDetails()->update($business_data);` in any time?

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan In your way, given data parsed to SQL query directly. In my way, given data are sent to a model object and then parsed to SQL query according to the business logic in the model. Is it a mass assignment or not? I'm not sure, but it's the way it is. You can make an update operation both ways; you should choose your path according to your needs.